# Nom parser that skips escaped terminator characters

Tags: regex, parsing, rust, parser-combinators

I've checked the other SO answers for nom parser combinator questions, but this one doesn't seem to have been asked yet.

I am attempting to parse delimited regular expressions, they will always be delimited with `/...../`, perhaps with the modifiers at the end (which for *all* the data I need to parse right now is out of scope.) *however* if there's an escaped `\/` in the middle of the string, my parser is stopping prematurely, on the first `/` even if it was preceeded with a `\`.

I have this parser:

```rust
use nom::bytes::complete::{tag, take_until};
use nom::{combinator::map_res, sequence::tuple, IResult};
use regex::Regex;

pub fn regex(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Regex> {
    map_res(
        tuple((tag("/"), take_until("/"), tag("/"))),
        |(_, re, _)| Regex::new(re),
    )(input)
}
```

Naturally the `take_until` stops at the first `/` without noticing that the previous character was a `\`, I've looked at `peek` and `recognize`, and `map` and a whole bunch of other things, but I'm just coming up short, I feel like I literally want `take_until("/")` with some kind of either encoding awareness, or simply .. I am anyway, using `map_res` to hand-off to Rust's `regex` crate to do the parsing.

I also tried something like this using the `escaped` combinator, but the examples are somewhat unclear and I couldn't make it work:

```rust
pub fn regex(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Regex> {
    map_res(
        tuple((
            tag("/"),
            escaped(many1(anychar), '\\', one_of(r"/")),
            tag("/"),
        )),
        |(_, re, _)| {
            println!("mapres {}", re);
            Regex::new(re)
        },
    )(input)
}
```

My test cases are as such (the `.unwrap().as_str()` is just to have a small example, since `regex::Regex` doesn't implement `PartialEq`):

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::regex;
    use super::Regex;
    #[test]
    fn test_parse_regex_simple() {
        assert_eq!(
            Regex::new(r#"hello world"#).unwrap().as_str(),
            regex("/hello world/").unwrap().1.as_str()
        );
    }
    #[test]
    fn test_parse_regex_with_escaped_forwardslash() {
        assert_eq!(
            Regex::new(r#"hello /world"#).unwrap().as_str(),
            regex(r"/hello \/world/").unwrap().1.as_str(),
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parser passed as the first argument to `escaped()` should parse *one* character that is *not the escape character*, *and* stop on the correct character(s). `many1(anychar)` does not answer any of these conditions.

Rather, you should call it this way:

```rust
escaped(none_of(r"\/"), '\\', one_of(r"/"))
```

Or the whole expression:

```rust
map_res(
    tuple((
        tag("/"),
        escaped(none_of(r"\/"), '\\', one_of(r"/")),
        tag("/"),
    )),
    |(_, re, _)| Regex::new(re),
)(input)
```

But it doesn't work. Because [`Regex`'s escape sequences don't include `/`](https://docs.rs/regex/1.5.6/regex/#escape-sequences). So you need to strip the escape characters. Luckily, [`escaped_transform()`](https://docs.rs/nom/latest/nom/bytes/complete/fn.escaped_transform.html) is here to help you:

```rust
map_res(
    tuple((
        tag("/"),
        escaped_transform(none_of(r"\/"), '\\', one_of(r"/")),
        tag("/"),
    )),
    |(_, re, _)| Regex::new(&re), // We need a little `&` here because `escape_transform()` returns a `String` but `Regex::new()` wants `&str`
)(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer from Chayim Friedman is correct, I however was able to extend it also to handle `\w` `\d` and other such modifiers thusly, it's simply an extension of Chayim's idea in the `escaped_transform` version:

```rust
pub fn regex(input: &str) -> IResult<&str, Regex> {
    map_res(
        delimited(
            tag("/"),
            escaped_transform(
                none_of("\\/"),
                '\\',
                alt((
                    value(r"/", tag("/")),
                    value(r"\d", tag("d")),
                    value(r"\W", tag("W")),
                    value(r"\w", tag("w")),
                    value(r"\b", tag("b")),
                    value(r"\B", tag("B")),
                )),
            ),
            tag("/"),
        ),
        |re| Regex::new(&re),
    )(input)
}
```

note this list is also incomplete, but https://docs.rs/regex/1.5.6/regex/#escape-sequences gives a complete set of escapes, and https://github.com/Geal/nom/blob/main/examples/string.rs gives a more detailed explanation of how to handle `\u{....}` type escape sequences.